# Simple IPV6 Address Question

Tags: ip-address, ipv6

I have a /96 block of IPV6 addresses and i'm wondering how i could some how find the next address (Since ipv6 addresses can contain numbers and letters). I know the first address could be in numbers but i've yet to find out how i could really find in some kind of order for that amount of addresses

E.G: What technique could i use to make sure i'll actually be able to use all of the addresses

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com/serverfault.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parts of an IPv6 address are 16-bit wide hexadecimal numbers. Read up on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal if you don't know what that means.

Once you understand hexadecimal numbers, finding the 'next address' is easy. Once you reach ffff for one part of your address, wrap around to 0 and increase the part to the left of it.

Comment: Thanks but i still don't understand how i can do this.

Answer (score 0):

the ipv6 adress subparts(whatever they are called) are in **hexadecimal** if i am not wrong

check this [link](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~mef/research/napt/reports/usenix98/index.html) for nomenclature details.